# Async function call not yielding any results to parent calling function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, angularfire

I am trying to retrieve a document field value given a documentID. I have solved the db calling part, but I cannot send the data back up. It's almost as if the function `this.userDbService.getVendorNameFromUserId`
below isn't being called at all.

Here is the parent function:

```
async getVendorName() {
  let name;

  //blindtiger not going here.

  //calling to 'private userDbService: UserDbService'
   name = await this.userDbService.getVendorNameFromUserId('2OD1yTnMrecMgqljvHFHDjug1VT2');
   console.log(name);
   return name.toString();}
```

and here is the function getVendorNameFromUserId(''):

```
 async getVendorNameFromUserId(id: string): Promise<string> {
    let vendorName = '';
    const userCollectionRef = await doc(this.store, 'clients/' + id);


    await docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}).forEach(el => {

      //correctly is 'blindtiger' from db call.
      console.log(el['user'].companyName.toString())
      return el['user'].companyName.toString();
    });
    //parent function doesn't yield any results - as if this is not called.
    // It should yield 'blindtiger' here.
    return 'NOT FOUND';
  }
```

getVendorName() is being called within the constructor of a typescript file, the value of this function result is then being used to get all products for that vendor name.

```
  constructor(private shopifyService: ShopifyService, private userDbService: UserDbService, private modalService: NgbModal, private userAuthService: UserAuthService, private itemDb: ItemDbService) {
    let vendorName: string;

    const name = this.getVendorName();
    console.log(name);
    this.getAllProducts(name).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.itemsToSell = result;
    });
  }`
```

I have a feeling I am missing something async related - buy would love any advice on why the value 'blindtiger' isn't even being passed up the chain at all.

I have tried adding async await to the function call - getVendorNameFromUserId(). If I remove the await keyword in from of docData() here:

```
    await docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}).forEach(el => {

      //correctly is 'blindtiger' from db call.
      console.log(el['user'].companyName.toString())
      return el['user'].companyName.toString();
    });`
```

I get the result 'NOT FOUND' - which suggests this passes data up the chain correctly. I am thinking there is a problem with this function not being waited on by the calling function which looks like this:

```
 async getVendorName() {
    let name;

    //blindtiger not going here.

    //calling to 'private userDbService: UserDbService'
    name = await this.userDbService.getVendorNameFromUserId('2OD1yTnMrecMgqljvHFHDjug1VT2');
    console.log(name);
    return name.toString();
  }
```

docData returns an observable.

```
const data = await docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
  vendorName = user['user'].companyName;

  //does not yield blind tiger
  console.log({dataDone: vendorName});
})

//does yield blind tiger
console.log({dataAfter: vendorName})
return vendorName['user'].companyName
```

}

Comment: When you call `docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'})` you expect an array with one item?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `docData()` returns an array where you just need the first value, since the method-signature reads `getVendorNameFromUserId` and you pass exactly one `id`. Therefore your code could look as follows:

```
async getVendorName() {
    const name = await this.userDbService.getVendorNameFromUserId('2OD1yTnMrecMgqljvHFHDjug1VT2');
    console.log('name', name);
    return name;
}

async getVendorNameFromUserId(id: string): Promise<string> {
    const userCollectionRef = await doc(this.store, 'clients/' + id);
    console.log('userCollectionRef', userCollectionRef);

    const resultArray = await firstValueFrom(docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}));
    console.log('resultArray', resultArray);

    // Get the first element from array, given the array has at least one element
    const vendorName = resultArray?.map(el => el.user.companyName.toString())?.[0];
    return vendorName ?? 'NOT FOUND';
}
```

**Please note**: You don't need to write `toString()` in `getVendorName()`, since `getVendorNameFromUserId()` already returns a promise of type `string`.

Comment: Thanks for this - and apologies for not clarifying. docData returns an observable. I have tried this code just now: `const data = await docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => { 
      vendorName = user['user'].companyName;

      //does not yield blind tiger
      console.log({dataDone: vendorName});
    })

    //does yield blind tiger
    console.log({dataAfter: vendorName})
    return vendorName['user'].companyName
  }` and have updated my question to include this. You can see I get the correct result during the subscribe call, but not after.

Comment: I adapted my code now. In order to not complicate things too much I just added `firstValueFrom` where I call the `docData()` method. This basically converts the observable into a promise and therefore you will just get the first emission. It also allows you to continue working with `await` instead of having to subscribe to an observable manually. Can you try again? I actually tested it locally while mocking the API-calls. If it still doesn't work I could also create a stackblitz example ;-).

Comment: Btw: I assume that `doc()` returns a promise, or does it also return an observable?

Comment: Thank you - docData() does return an observable, and firstValueFrom() turns this observable into a promise. I could get the code to work by removing the map (as it's now a promise). So `const resultArray = await firstValueFrom(docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'}));` and then `return resultArray['user'].companyName ?? 'NOT FOUND';` I now need to follow @alexis-deprez advice and look into using APP_INITIALIZER so I'm not adding an await in the constructor.

Comment: The functions provided at APP_INITIALIZER are executed during app startup. I'm not 100% sure if that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You have a return in your foreach : it will return result for the foreach, not the `getVendorNameFromUserId`. Use regular forof instead

```
async getVendorNameFromUserId(id: string): Promise<string> {
  let vendorName = '';
  const userCollectionRef = await doc(this.store, 'clients/' + id);


  const data = await docData(userCollectionRef, {idField: 'id'});
  for (const el of data) { 
    //it will return the first found. Don't you need condition to search from criterias?
    //correctly is 'blindtiger' from db call.
    console.log(el['user'].companyName.toString())
    return el['user'].companyName.toString();
  }
  //parent function doesn't yield any results - as if this is not called.
  // It should yield 'blindtiger' here.
  return 'NOT FOUND';
}
```

- bonus : avoid async in constructors, for async init you can use APP_INITIALIZER in Angular.